# Database in package takes wrong path

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, path, package

I included a `sqlite3` database in a package of mine. the path of the database file is:

```
db_file="szs.db"
```

But if I try to access the database from my main application so it creates a new database in the root of the main application instead using the one in the package. How can I fix the path so it will get the database in my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem occurs because you access `"szs.db"` using a relative path.

this is my standard answer to relative/absolute paths in python: [Python ConfigParser cannot search .ini file correctly (Ubuntu 14, Python 3.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670) .

that should solve your problem.