# Iterating the content of a text file in python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file named 'triple_response.txt' which contain the some text as :

```
(1,(db_name,string),DSP)
(1,(rel, id),2)
(2,(rel_name, string),DataSource)
(2,(tuple, id),201)
(2,(tuple, id),202)
(2,(tuple, id),203)
(201,(src_id,varchar),Pos201510070)
(201,(src_name,varchar),Postgres)
(201,(password,varchar),root)
(201,(host,varchar),localhost)
(201,(created_date,date),2015-10-07)
(201,(user_name,varchar),postgres)
(201,(src_type,varchar),Structured)
(201,(db_name,varchar),postgres)
(201,(port,numeric),None)
(202,(src_id,varchar),pos201510060)
(202,(src_name,varchar),Postgres)
(202,(password,varchar),root)
(202,(host,varchar),localhost)
(202,(created_date,date),2015-10-06)
(202,(user_name,varchar),postgres)
(202,(src_type,varchar),Structured)
(202,(db_name,varchar),DSP)
(202,(port,numeric),5432)
(203,(src_id,varchar),pos201510060)
(203,(src_name,varchar),Postgres)
(203,(password,varchar),root)
(203,(host,varchar),localhost)
(203,(created_date,date),2015-10-06)
(203,(user_name,varchar),postgres)
(203,(src_type,varchar),Structured)
(203,(db_name,varchar),maindb)
(203,(port,numeric),5432)
```

I am trying to convert these contents into JSON using a python script:

```
import re
import collections
import json, jsonpickle


def convertToJSON(File):
    word_list=[]
    row_list = []
    try:
        with open(File,'r') as f:
            for word in f:
                word_list.append(word)


        with open(File,'r+') as f:
            for row in f:
                print row
                row_list.append(row.split())

        column_list = zip(*row_list)
    except IOError:
        print "Error in opening file.."
    triple =""
    for t in word_list:
        triple+=t

    tripleList = re.findall(r"\([^\(^\)]*\)",triple)
    idList = re.split(r"\([^\(^\)]*\)",triple)

    i =0
    jsonDummy = []
    jsonData = {}
    for trip in tripleList:
        nameAndType = re.split(r",|:",trip)

        if(i==0):
                key = re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub("",idList[i])
        else:
            try:
                key = re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub("",idList[i].split("(")[1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
        i = i+1
        if(idList[i].find('(')!=-1):
            try:
                content = re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub("",idList[i].split(")")[0])

            except IndexError:
                pass
        else:
            content = re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub("",idList[i])
        try:
            trip = trip[1:-1]
            tripKey = trip[1]

        except IndexError:
            tripKey = ''
        name = re.compile("[^\w']").sub("",nameAndType[0])
        try:
            typeName = re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub("",nameAndType[1])
        except IndexError:
            typeName = 'String'

        tripDict = dict()
        value = dict()

        value[name] = content
        tripDict[key]=value

        jsonDummy.append(tripDict)

    for j in jsonDummy:
        for k,v in j.iteritems():
            jsonData.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    data = dict()
    data['data'] = jsonData
    obj = {}
    obj=jsonpickle.encode(data, unpicklable=False)

    return obj

    pass
```

I am calling this function convertToJSON() within the same file as:

print convertToJSON("triple_response.txt")

I am getting the output as i expect like:

```
{"data": {"1": [{"db_name": "DSP"}, {"rel": "2"}], "201": [{"src_id": "Pos201510070"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151007"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "postgres"}, {"port": "None"}], "203": [{"src_id": "pos201510060"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151006"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "maindb"}, {"port": "5432"}], "2": [{"rel_name": "DataSource"}, {"tuple": "201"}, {"tuple": "202"}, {"tuple": "203"}], "202": [{"src_id": "pos201510060"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151006"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "DSP"}, {"port": "5432"}]}}
```

Now the problem which i am facing, which i am calling this from the outside the class as:

```
def extractConvertData(self):
       triple_response = SPO(source, db_name, table_name, response)
       try:
           _triple_file = open('triple_response.txt','w+')
           _triple_file.write(triple_response)
           print "written data in file.."
           with open('triple_response.txt','r+') as f:
                for word in f:
                    print word
           jsonData = convertToJSON(str('triple_response.txt')) 
       except IOError:
           print "Not able to open a file"
       print "Converted into JSON"
       print jsonData
       pass
```

The same code of convertToJSON() is not working...

It neither giving any output nor giving any error, it is not able to read the content from the 'triple_response.txt' file in the line.

```
with open('triple_response.txt','r+') as f:
    for word in f:
        print word
```

Any one can tell me solution to this problem..

Comment: "calling this from outside the class?" I don't see any classes defined.

Comment: Does the script that contains `extractConvertData` exist in the same directory as `triple_response.txt` ?

Comment: your file can not be found because you address it using a relative path - this is my standard answer to relative vs absolute paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670 .

Comment: And also `_triple_file = open('triple_response.txt','w+')` is not closed.

Comment: write `print` statements in functions and check from where code break

Comment: As @sobolevn pointed out, _triple_file is never closed (except implicitly when you end the Python process, which is a terrible practice). I'm getting vague flashbacks that **you can get platform-specific behavior when you have dangling filehandles like that** (what is your platform? Unix? Windows?). So don't. Make sure to close it after you write it (`_triple_file.write(triple_response)`). And in fact test that that file is non-zero, using `os.stat()`. And assert that that's nonzero, otherwise raise an Exception.

Comment: Yes, both are in same directory....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_triple_file` is never closed (except implicitly when you end the Python process, which is a terrible practice).

You can get platform-specific behavior when you have dangling filehandles like that (what is your platform? Unix? Windows?). Probably the write to `_triple_file` is not getting flushed.
So don't leave it dangling. Make sure to close it after you write it: (_triple_file.write(triple_response)). And in fact then assert that that file length is non-zero, using `os.stat()`, otherwise raise an Exception.

Also, you only have one big try...except clause to catch all errors, this is too much in one bite. Break it into two separate try...except clauses for writing `_triple_file`, and then reading it back. (Btw you might like to use `tempfile` library instead, to sidestep needing to know your intermediate file's pathname).

Something like the following untested pseudocode:

```
   triple_response = SPO(source, db_name, table_name, response)
   try:
       _triple_file = open('triple_response.txt','w+')
       _triple_file.write(triple_response)
       _triple_file.close()
   except IOError:
       print "Not able to write intermediate JSON file"
       raise 

   assert [suitable expression involving os.stat('triple_response.txt') to test size > 0 ], "Error: intermediate JSON file was empty"

   try:
       with open('triple_response.txt','r+') as f:
            for word in f:
                print word
       jsonData = convertToJSON(str('triple_response.txt')) 
   except IOError:
       print "Not able to read back intermediate JSON file"
       #raise  # if you want to reraise the exception

   ...
```