# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

i have the following code that is attempting to start each of the "commands" below. The module attempts to open a second program and cashes

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv, exit
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from collections import defaultdict
from os import path, remove

def main():
if len(argv) != 4 or not argv[2] in ['C', 'G', 'A', 'D']:
    print("Cas-OFFinder-bulge v1.1 beta (2015-09-30)")
    print("")
    print("Copyright (c) 2015 Jeongbin Park and Sangsu Bae")
    print("")
    print("Usage: cas-offinder-bulge {input_file} {C|G|A|D} {output_file}")
    print("(C: using CPUs, G: using GPUs, A: using accelerators, D: dry-run")
    print("")
    print("Example input file (DNA bulge 2, RNA bulge 1):")
    print("/var/chromosomes/human_hg19")
    print("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNRG 2 1")
    print("GGCCGACCTGTCGCTGACGCNNN 5")
    print("CGCCAGCGTCAGCGACAGGTNNN 5")
    print("ACGGCGCCAGCGTCAGCGACNNN 5")
    print("GTCGCTGACGCTGGCGCCGTNNN 5")
    print("")
    p = Popen(['cas-offinder'], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    flag = False
    for line in p.stdout:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "Available device list:":
            flag = True
        if flag:
            print(line)
else:
    fnhead = path.join(path.dirname(argv[1]), path.splitext(path.basename(argv[1]))[0])
    with open(argv[1]) as f:
        chrom_path = f.readline()
        pattern, bulge_dna, bulge_rna = f.readline().strip().split()
        isreversed = False
        for i in range(int(len(pattern)/2)):
            if pattern[i] == 'N' and pattern[len(pattern)-i-1] != 'N':
                isreversed = False
                break
            elif pattern[i] != 'N' and pattern[len(pattern)-i-1] == 'N':
                isreversed = True
                break
```

Upon executing the code the following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./cas-offinder-bulge", line 154, in <module>
main()
File "./cas-offinder-bulge", line 24, in main
p = Popen(['cas-offinder'], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think I'm missing something, can anyone point out the mistakes?
- Thanks

Comment: Properly indent your code. That is not a valid python program.

Comment: The program can't find the file `cas-offinder`?

Comment: the path to your executable is relative... try the absolute  path. see this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670 .

Comment: can you execute that program from the terminal using `./cas-offinder` ? it seems to me like it cannot find the executable.