# the file path error in python program

Tags: python

write a python program in pycharm,

the program:

```
log_file_name = os.path.join("log","log_"+glovar.date+".txt")
print(log_file_name)
if os.path.isfile(log_file_name):
    #if the log file has exist,append new content at the end of the file
    log_file = open(log_file_name,"a")
else:
    #if the log file not exist, create it and write the content in
    print(log_file_name)
    log_file = open("log\log_20161219.txt","w+")
```

the error is :

```
C:\Python\Python36\python.exe    C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py
log\log_20161219.txt
log\log_20161219.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py", line 144, in     <module>
log_write("likes","success",user_count,user_addr_name)
File "C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py", line 29, in   log_write
log_file = open("log\log_20161219.txt","w+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log\\log_20161219.txt'
```

what is the problem and how to solve it, your timely reply will be highly appreciated

Comment: your file can not be found because you address it using a relative path - this
is my standard answer to relative vs absolute paths:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670 .

Comment: to add a comment: the `log` directory doesn't exist in the current dir.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use an absolute path if you are not launching your python script in the parent directory of folder "log".

You can use this to get rid of your relative path :

```
root = r"C:\this\is\root\path"
log_folder = os.path.join(root, r"log")
log_file = log_file = os.path.join(root, "log","log20161219.txt") #edit JF-Fabre
```

As Jean-François Fabre mention, if the directory doesn't exist, you have to create it before :

```
if not os.path.exists(log_folder) :
    os.makedirs(log_folder)
```

Comment: that is _bad_: `root = 'C:\this\is\root\path'` creates a path with a tabulation and a carriage return. and creating a directory when you don't know where you are is bound to fail too.

Comment: and `log_file = os.path.join(log_folder, "log20161219.txt")` is better too

Comment: I left "root" as it'll still work if he doesn't need log_folder.

Comment: okay then `log_file = os.path.join(root, "log","log20161219.txt")`