# How can I print the contents of a file at a set interval using Python?

Tags: python, delay, intervals

I have a file that resembles the following:

```
Entry #1
Entry #2
Entry #3
Entry #4
Entry #5
```

I want to print the lines of this file with a 2 second delay between lines. How can this be done? Thank you in advance.

Edit: This is the code I've decided to use based on the help I've received. Thank you.

```
from time import sleep
with open('c:\Output.txt', 'r', 0) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: what is the `count` for? you `sleep` in any case (`count >= 0` is always true). and (as stated in my answer) there is no guarantee that `print` will really print something on the console right *now* if you do not `flush` the output...

Comment: I see. So I could eliminate count+=1 and the following if statement. I'm still trying to understand flush. Thank you for the help.

Comment: yes, your `count` has no effect. there is not much magic in `flush`; `print` prints to a buffer (`sys.stdout`) which holds the data and decides when it is ready to print it to the console (this is more efficient than printing at every `print` statement). with `flush` you force the buffer to do that *now*.

Comment: I don't understand how to use flush in this instance (or sys.stdout). Could you show me where it fits? I'm two days new to python. Thank you for you time and patients.

Comment: `print 'hello'` is short for `sys.stdout.write('hello')`. maybe this helps a bit? http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/stdin_stdout_stderr.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have file with data - you can easily real lines from it

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

and then you can print every line with 2 seconds (or what you want) interval

```
from time import sleep
for l in lines:
    print(l.strip())
    sleep(2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep # The time module is used for delays.
for i in range(20):
    print ("Entry #%d" % (i))
    sleep(2) # sleep(amount of seconds you want to delay).
```

I hope this was the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       print(line.strip())
       time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant (to the eyes of this beginner!) Thank you for the quick response. This works very well. Could you tell me...Is this code better in any way than the code I added in my edited question? Is there anything wrong with the code I came up with?

Comment: @aConvolutedConscious your code works well, but you could do better by avoiding absolute path in the open() by using "os.path" to get the file name in order to make your code portable, also avoid using multiple commands in 1 line.

Comment: How do I use os.path in this instance? Thank you.

Comment: here is an example on how you could do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30625670/4954037

Answer (score 0):

[`time.sleep(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) makes the interpreter wait for n seconds. note that you may have to [`flush`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) if you print very short text; the output is buffered and may not write to the console at every `print` statement.

this is for **python2**

```
import sys
from time import sleep

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fle:
    for line in fle:
       print line.strip()  # don't print an additional '\n'
       sys.stdout.flush()  # make sure this is written to the console *now*
       sleep(2)
```

in **python3** you can do this:

```
from time import sleep

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
       print(line, flush=True, end='')  # don't print an additional '\n'
       sleep(2)
```

also make sure the interpreter finds your file when using a relative path. more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625670/4954037).