# Error during opening csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, import

I saved csv file in (C:/Users/kgu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test1.py). named as `testdata.csv`

my code is :

```
import csv
f=open('testdata.csv','r',encoding='utf-8')
```

And the error message is here :

```
C:\Users\kgu\Anaconda3\python.exe 
C:/Users/kgu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kgu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
f=open('testdata.csv','r',encoding='utf-8')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testdata.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I did save the `testdata.csv` in  the python project folder.
I don't know what is wrong in it.

Comment: Where do you run it from? (working directory), what is in this dir? what is the full path of the file?

Comment: you should check whether your csv file is in the same directory as your python script.

Comment: place your csv at C:/Users/kgu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/

Comment: @HariomSingh Oh there was a mistake. I did it like what you said.But it doesn't work at all..

Comment: Try placing any text file there and remove the encoding part..make sure csv is not already open

Comment: does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670

Answer (score 1):

If you use Pandas, you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = "/yourfilepath/yourfile.csv"
# check your sep (";" , "," ...)
f = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding="utf-8", sep="yoursep")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this - if you are in the right working directory:

```
with open(testdata.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = [x for x in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='yourdelimiter')]
```