# Cannot open file with xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

The error says

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test2.xls'

but I've cross-checked the name several times.

```
rb = xlrd.open_workbook("test2.xls", 'w')
# make a writable copy of the opened excel file
wb = copy(rb)
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path ? Where is your file located ? Where is your code located ? Please provide more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ConfigParser cannot search .ini file correctly (Ubuntu 14, Python 3.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4)

Comment: yes i have,        file_location=r"C:\Users\320035046\Music\tezt\test2.xls"
rb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location, 'w')

Comment: The subdirectory "tezt" is no typo?

Comment: No its not, but its fixed now. Problem with excel file creation. Thank you for the help.